# Would it be possible to edit the CIL (MSIL) instructions of an already existing property set function call?

Tags: c#, cil

I know we can define types, methods, properties and constructors at runtime with the TypeBuilder Class.

Now I would like to know if it is possible to edit a function CIL(MSIL) codeflow at runtime. (Or at least set another function as a set accessor)

To test things out I created a Dummy class like this:

```cs
public class DummyClass
{
    public long prop1 { get; set; }

    public SampleClass()
    {
    }
}
```

And I would like to edit its set function to always set the value `-1`.
The best I achieved is to access the setter CIL(MSIL) instructions like this :

```cs
var ILInstructionAsByteArray = typeof(DummyClass).GetProperties()[0].GetSetMethod().GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray()
```

Is it even possible ?

Comment: If the assembly containing this class is already loaded than AFAIK you cannot modify it anymore. All modifications have to happen before it gets loaded

Comment: Depending on your requirements you can try to use Harmony (see an example here: https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony/blob/master/HarmonyTests/Patching/DynamicMethodPatches.cs)

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I don't know if it directly answer the question but if you want to add an answer I would accept it.